# New App Engine Application not showing up on Start Page?

Tags: google-app-engine

I just created an App Engine account, and clicked the Create an Application button to register my application id.  After submitting the form, I was also able to upload a hello-world application to my app and it runs fine:

http://aebootcamp-mckoss.appspot.com

But when I visit my App Engine application console page:

http://appengine.google.com/

There are NO APPLICATIONS LISTED!  Instead it redirects me to:

http://appengine.google.com/start

to prompt me to create my first application on App Engine.

I've successfully done this using a @gmail.com account.  The account I'm having trouble with is also my email address for a Google Apps (for domains) account.  Could there be a bug with these accounts working with App Engine?

Comment: I've posted a bug in the App Engine Issue Tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2946

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sign in at http://appengine.google.com/a/yourdomain to access apps created with an Apps account.

Comment: I had the same problem, and sure enough the app is under my apps account for that email address even though I was logged in under the normal google account

Comment: You're a genius!  Since I have both a Google Account for this email address AND a Google Apps Account, it provisioned the app on the Apps Account - but I didn't know how to log in to it for App Engine to see it!